# Cannot find updated/modified date in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having some problems with updating the date. In the controller, I have implemented a logic where it saves the current date and as per validation in Model, it successfully saves it in DB. The problem occurs when I try updating the date in Edit Controller, it removes CreatedDate and also doesn't save the updated date as well.
Images are attached:
[image]
[image]
[image]What I was expecting to do was implement Update logic that should save data in "UpdateDate" but it does not work.

Create Controller:
[image]

Edit Controller:
[image]

Is there any way to handle this without dealing with Entity or EntityState?

Comment: Don't post code as images. In your code `notesInList.CreationDate` can only be populated from the http request form. I would reload the object from the database instead.

Comment: how can i do it can you please guide. As mentioned, this data is being stored in DB but when I go in edit mode, it removes CreationDate and UpdateDate from the DB. Same logic notesInList.CreationDate = DateTime.Now is being used to update datetime.